# C++ - Make a string+int set stl type

Tags: c++, types, stl, set, multiset

my question is: is it possible to create a multitype stl set? If a want to calculate the occurrences number from a text file, how can I do? I need to use only  or ...

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string, int> danteh;
    set<string>::iterator iterator_danteh;
    ifstream d1("text.txt");
    ofstream d2("output.txt");
    string word;
    while(!d1.eof())
    {
        d1 >> word;
        danteh.insert(word);

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "FINE!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You likely want to use a std::map instead (Also: Do not test streams for eof, but for a successfule extraction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) from `<map>` header, like:

```
std::map< std::string, int > danteh ;  // Key is the std::string, 
                                       //  value is the int
```

For counting words , simply use following logic :

```
while ( d1 >> word ) // Extract word from stream
{
   danteh[word]++;   // Add into map and increment the count
}
```

For iterating through map, use iterators as you use it for set, difference is `first` (key) will give you the word as `second`(value) will give you its frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::multiset` instead of the `std::set`. `multiset` is defined in the same header:

```
#include <set>
```

As the name suggests, the difference between `set` and `multiset` is that the `multiset` can contain multiple copies of the same value.

Inserting the strings works just like with the `set` you used before:

```
std::multiset<std::string> danteh;
...
while(!d1.eof())
{
    d1 >> word;
    danteh.insert(word);
}
```

Once the set is built, you can retrieve the occurrence count of a given word with:

```
danteh.count("hello");
```